# Implement a chess app for Android with Stockfish

Tags: engines, programming, android

I want to implement a chess app for Android with Stockfish.

I downloaded the Stockfish binary source code, but I don't know how to use engine

Please tell me how to use Stockfish engine for programming.

Answer (score 3):

@Glorfindel is absolutely correct (+1). To get you started, do this:

1. Read UCI specification (http://wbec-ridderkerk.nl/html/UCIProtocol.html)
2. Download Droidfish source and check how it interacts with the engine
3. Learn how to compile Stockfish with JNI
4. Create an empty Android project. Send the engine `isready`. Do you get anything back from Stockfish?

Answer (score 2):

Stockfish is written in C++, so in order to call it from your Android app (which I presume is written in Java), you need to call its library via JNI (Java Native Interface). This is a rather technical task better suited for Stack Overflow; [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007693/call-c-library-from-java-in-android) is a question to get started.

If you encounter specific problems while doing this, you can ask a question there; in it's current form it is way too broad. Afterwards, you might need to find out which *methods* to call (e.g. to evaluate a certain position, or to suggest the best move). That's something we'd be able to answer here, provided that you have a very specific question.

Comment: Um.. I want guidline How to use library
eg. Google provide how to use google map, Blutooth lib... 
Please give me basic guidline

Comment: Do you give me engine Importing - guidline?

Comment: @조남진 sorry, that would be too long for this format. If you need a  step-by-step instruction on how to do this specific task, you will have a very hard time creating a properly functioning mobile app anyway.

Comment: @조남진 My answer is the guideline. If you can't follow my suggestions, you are not going to able to do anything.

Comment: @StudentT yes, we have it pretty much covered between our two answers. If that doesn't help the OP, I'm voting to close as too broad.